# Using only Multiplication and Integers, how can I 'divide' a number?

Tags: javascript, html, css, algorithm, math

### The problem:

The API I'm using for building stacks in rapidweaver doesn't allow for division or floats, but I essentially want to divide a number by another number.

### The relevant rules of the API:

The API is placed inside html, css, and javascript files and is compiled into actual html, css, and javascript before generating the project files.

1. In this API each mathematical operation is wrapped in:

   `%( math )%`
2. So to achieve (1 + 3) * 6 it'd be:

   `%( %( 1 + 3 )% * 6 )%`

   Using `%( 1 + 3 * 6 )%` would break it, only one operation is allowed inside each `%()%`.
3. Also, I can use variables which will represent user input

   `%id=variableName%`
4. So, if I want to multiply user input by 2 I can do:

   `%( %id=variableName% * 2 )%`

### What I want to do:

`%( %id=CB_seconds% / 2 )%` OR `%( %id=CB_seconds% * 0.5 )%`

But ^these^ are not allowed for some stupid reason...

I want to take the user input `%id=CB_seconds%`, and divide it in half. The user will define `%id=CB_seconds%` as an integer between 0 and 10,000. I need both the original value and the divided value in different areas. One possible solution is to have the user specify a value between 0 and 5,000 and multiply this value by two. However, this wont work because the user is defining the length of an animation and it's confusing to ask them to specify half the length they really want.

### My Question

Is there some way to get half of a number using ONLY integers and multiplication/addition/subtraction, and without knowing what the number will be before hand?

---

Here's the documentation for the Stacks API - https://yourhead.tenderapp.com/kb/stacks-api/templates

Comment: You got access to any bitwise operations? Id hazard a guess not if you are already limited. Stupid question but had to ask :)

Comment: Is there a limit on the size of numbers you have to deal with? If so, can you do array operations? You can make an array that maps all numbers to `number/2`.

Comment: @brumScouse No bitwise operations, but that's a good question.

Comment: @Barmar I can't use arrays :/ All I have are strings and integers.

Comment: I find this very difficult to believe. What kind of crazy idiot would create a mathematical language with no division? Why would they do that? Are you really sure you're not missing something? Can you provide a link to the documentation?

Comment: I know, right? maybe I've missed something. Here's the link - https://yourhead.tenderapp.com/kb/stacks-api/templates

Comment: "Inline Math" is the relevant section, it says, "Behavior with non-integer values is undefined. Can be any of: +, -, *, ==, !=, &&, ||, <, <=, >, >="

Comment: If you just want to get the half, for even numbers you can multiply by 10 and remove the last character (10/2 >> 10 * 5>> 50 >> 5)

Comment: Make a contribution and add division to the API.

Comment: @juvian it depends much on the engine processing the template, how could it know to remove the last char (and then perform some parsing/converting to get the number)? if we can modify that ***bad*** engine, we can even simply use the division operator there.

Comment: @robbmj I'd love to make a contribution, but Isaac(the creator of stacks) is pretty secretive about stacks and I doubt he would allow me to access the code.

Comment: Create a variable with 0.5 and multiply *that*.

Comment: @hellaFont: Ugh.  Then stop using the thing now instead of digging a bigger and bigger hole for future you.

Comment: @tmyklebu: I know, it's for work and I can't really avoid it unless I want to find another job. Maybe that's the best idea though haha.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## If you only have access to `+` and `*`, it is not possible.

This is mathematic:

If you had a function that would be written with only addition and multiplication such as:

```
a/b=f(a,b)
```

You can expand f into a polynomial function.

If you take n growing to infinity

You will have `f(n,n)=n/n=1`

But polynomials always tend to +infinite, -infinite, or 0, so such a function could not exist.

Comment: Any *nonconstant* polynomial tends to either positive or negative infinity.  (And a constant polynomial, like `f(a, b) = 1`, obviously can't equal `a/b` for all choices of `a` and `b`.)

Answer (score 2):

The same way you can define multiplication as a series of additions, you can make a division as a series of subtractions. To do so, you need looping and comparison capabilities. To divide a by b, assuming that both are integers and that `a > b`, your pseudocode would be:

```
division = 1
c = a - b
while (c > b)
  c = c - b
  division = division + 1
end while
```

at this point you have `a / b = division` and the remainder is `c`.

An exemple, `a  = 10` and `b = 3`:

```
division = 1
c = 10 - 3 = 7

c (=7) > 3 --> Continue
  c = 7 - 3 = 4
  division = 2

c (= 4) > 3 --> Continue
  c = 4 - 3 = 1
  division =  3

c (= 1) < 3 --> Stop
```

At this point `division = 3` and `c = 1`, i.e., `10 / 3 = 3 (+ 1)`.

I saw that the Stacks API allows for comparison. If it also contains looping, then you can implement the above.

Having said all the above, it is really dumb that they don't have a division.

Comment: It appears you can use a `repeat` block to implement `for ( i = 0 ; i < n ; i++ ) {}` and nothing more.

Comment: @Teepeemm Bummer, that is really not the best loop for the task :-) You could still get away with it by setting n large enough (e.g. `n=a`) and breaking out of the loop when you reach the `c < b` condition. I did not really try to understand the API but I saw conditionals and a `%[endrepeat]%` variable that might (or not) be set to end the loop. But, to be honest, this is more of a puzzle exercise than anything really practical.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is truly bad coding,  but you could double each number from 1 to 5000 and see if it is the number which was used as input (also check if it's the number+1 to see for rounded fractions). Since it's just 5000 operations, it should not affect performance a lot.

Comment: +1: Though I suggest using the binary search technique to do it in O(log N) operations instead of O(N).

Answer (score 0):

**New answer**

Since we don’t really have loops, we’ll have to implement a binary search.  What we’d like to do is:

```
CB_copy = CB_seconds;
CB_half = 0;
for ( exp = 13 ; exp > 0 ; exp- - ) {
    if ( CB_copy > 1 << exp ) {
        CB_half += 1 << (exp-1);
        CB_copy -= 1 << exp;
    }
}
```

But we don’t have conditionals to speak of.  We can rewrite it using the comparisons we do have:

```
CB_copy = CB_seconds;
CB_half = 0;
for ( exp = 13 ; exp > 0 ; exp- - ) {
    CB_half += ( 1 << (exp-1) ) * ( CB_copy > 1 << exp );
    CB_copy -= ( 1 << exp ) * ( CB_copy > 1 << exp )
}
```

As mentioned, we don’t have loops.  So we have to unroll everything, and get 28 lines of code:

```
CB_copy = CB_seconds;
CB_half = 0;
CB_half += ( 1 << 12 ) * ( CB_copy > 1 << 13 );
CB_copy -= ( 1 << 13 ) * ( CB_copy > 1 << 13 );
CB_half += ( 1 << 11 ) * ( CB_copy > 1 << 12 );
CB_copy -= ( 1 << 12 ) * ( CB_copy > 1 << 12 );
. . .
CB_half += ( 1 << 1 ) * ( CB_copy > 1 << 2 );
CB_copy -= ( 1 << 2 ) * ( CB_copy > 1 << 2 );
CB_half += ( 1 << 0 ) * ( CB_copy > 1 << 1 );
CB_copy -= ( 1 << 1 ) * ( CB_copy > 1 << 1 );
```

We also don’t have bit shifting.  But we can get values from a custom plist.  So replace `1 << k` with `twoExp{k}`, for fourteen values of `k`, and have those constants in your plist:

```
CB_half += ( twoExp12 ) * ( CB_copy > twoExp13 );
CB_copy -= ( twoExp13 ) * ( CB_copy > twoExp13 );
etc
```

Finally, translate this into the correct syntax:

```
%CB_copy = %id=CB_seconds% %
%CB_half = 0%
%CB_half = %( CB_half + %( twoExp12 * %( CB_copy > twoExp13 )% )% )% %
%CB_copy = %( CB_copy - %( twoExp13 * %( CB_copy > twoExp13 )% )% )% %
. . .
%CB_half = %( CB_half + %( twoExp0 * %( CB_copy > twoExp1 )% )% )% %
%CB_copy = %( CB_copy - %( twoExp1 * %( CB_copy > twoExp1 )% )% )% %
```

28 lines of code to divide by 2.  Good luck.

---

**Old answer**

We can implement GrimRepear1908’s idea of looping up to 5000 and checking to see if doubling gets us the right value.  In a real language, what we’re going to do would look like:

```
for repeatIndex in (0..5001):
  CB_half += repeatIndex*( repeatIndex*2==CB_seconds || repeatIndex*2==CB_seconds+1 )
```

With the API, it seems that the code is readable only if you keep things to one operation per line, so this becomes:

```
for repeatIndex in (0..5001):
  doubled = repeatIndex*2
  doubledLessOne = doubled-1
  CB_evenTarget = doubled==CB_seconds
  CB_oddTarget = doubledLessOne==CB_second
  isTarget = CB_evenTarget || CB_oddTarget // is 0 or 1
  multed = repeatIndex * isTarget
  CB_half = multed + CB_half
```

And in the syntax of the language (assuming I’ve done variable assignment correctly), you end up with:

```
%[repeat 5001]%
%doubled = %( %id=repeatIndex% *2 )% %
%doubledLessOne = %( %id=doubled% -1 )%
%CB_evenTarget = %( %id=doubled% == %id=CB_seconds% )%
%CB_oddTarget = %( %id=doubledLessOne% == %id=CB_second% )%
%isTarget = %( %id=CB_evenTarget% || %id=CB_oddTarget% )%
%multed = %( %id=repeatIndex% * %id=isTarget% )%
%CB_half = %( %id=multed% + %id=CB_half% )%
%[endrepeat]%
```

Nuclearman suggested a binary search technique.  This would probably make the code shorter, but with the pain that a simple loop ended up with, I’m not going to try.

Comment: %[repeat]% is more like an angular ng-repeat in angular. It's not a loop. It evaluates any expressions and prints one for each iteration.

Comment: @hellaFont In that case, you may need to implement a binary search, but unroll the loop.  See my edit.